# How make clang-format indent using tabs instead of spaces?

Tags: clang-format

Testing with the following

`clang-format -style="{BasedOnStyle: Google, UseTab: Always}" -i /path/to/file.ino`

Results in spaces instead of tabs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Internally, `clang-format` only works with spaces, its not until the final step it replaces spaces with tabs and then it will only replace them in groups of `TabWidth`. Since the Google style has `IndentWidth: 2` and `TabWidth: 4` it wont replace them with tabs unless there are two indents on the same line.

You'll have to sync up `IndentWidth` and `TabWidth` in addition to `UseTab` for it to work on every line:

```yaml
UseTab: Always
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
```

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as the correct answer anymore as this alone does not cause clangformat to use tabs over spaces. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73498815/871617 is the correct answer and it is `UseTab`

Comment: I guess answer was edited and now is correct

Comment: Yep, it's correct now.

Comment: That really solves the problem with tabs used for indentation. However, the tabs used for aligning the comments at the ends of the lines are still converted to spaces depending on tab stop positions. Is there a way to disable converting existing tabs which are used to align comments and not for indentation? For example if there is `int a = 0xc9;<TAB><TAB>// comment` then tabs might still be converted to spaces.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `UseTab` option, for example:

```yaml
UseTab: Always
IndentWidth: 8
TabWidth: 8
```