# Is there a clang-format setting that will expand tabs to spaces in comments?

Tags: c, clang-format

I am using VSCode with clang-format, and I have the editor set to insert spaces for tabs, and I am using the following clang-format (LLVM v14.0.0) options:

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, UseTab: Never, IndentWidth: 4, TabWidth: 4, IndentCaseLabels: true, ColumnLimit: 0, BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, ReflowComments: true }"
```

However, if I format the following code, which has a mix of spaces and tabs in the comment block, the tabs inside the comment block are not replaced with spaces. (EDIT: It appears Stack Overflow's code block replaces all tabs with spaces..."This line has preceeding tabs" should have tab characters before the text.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * @brief       This is a comment with mixed spaces and tabs.
 *                      This line has preceeding tabs.
 */
int main()
{
    println("Hello, World!\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I've looked through the clang-format options but have been unable to figure out how to get clang-format to replace the tab characters with spaces inside the comment block.  Is there a clang-format option that will do this?

Comment: Although the question is 'backwards', does this help: [How make clang-format indent using tabs instead of spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69135590/10871073) ?

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for your response, but unfortunately no, that does not help.  I have the IndentWidth and TabWidth both set to 4 in my fallback options.  clang-format does replace tab characters that are not in comments with spaces, so I think it has to do with the tabs being in a comment.